# Data from AJAX PUT not being sent to the expressjs server

Tags: jquery, ajax, express, put

I'm pushing an AJAX "PUT" call to the backend.  I can't seem to get the 'req.body' object with the data from the AJAX call.

Does it have something to do with the `form.serialize()`?
Any suggestions?

**routes/index.js**

```
app.put('/:library/:book/:genre', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.book-name);
  res.send(200, {"youKnow":"putter"});  
});
```

**libraryBookForm.jade**

```
form#create-library-form(action='#', method='post')
      input(name="_method", value="PUT", type="hidden")
      div
        label Book
        input#book-name(type='text', name='book-name', required='required')
      div
        label Gender
        select#book-genre(name='book-genre')
          option(value='scifi') SciFi
          option(value='fantasy') Fantasy
      div
        input(type='submit', id='create-book-submit', value='Create Book')
```

**libraryBookAjax.js**

```
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
  url: '/publicLibrary/drawingBook/fantasy'
  type: 'PUT',
  contentType: 'application/json: charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: form.serialize()
}).done(function(msg) {
  alert("put success: " + msg);
}).fail(function(msg) {
  console.log("failure: " + msg);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `contentType` should not be what is stated above.

Changing it to
`contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"`
produces the correct result.